# Как получить самое большое id из mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица фото мне из нее надо получить максимально большое значение. Я попробовал так:

```
$sql = $mysql->query("SELECT max(id) FROM foto");
  print_r( $sql);
```

Но выводится `mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 1 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0 )`
Я так понимаю что все так и должно быть, как получить максимальное значение(всего 6 id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql_task  = 'SELECT max(id) as `макс` FROM foto ; ' ;

$sql = $mysql->query($sql_task);

if ( ! $sql )   {echo 'таблица foto пуста';die();}

$row = $sql->fetch_assoc();

echo 'максимальный id = '.$row['макс'];
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, а не можете объяснить почему в моем примере не выводилось?

Comment: Почитайте https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php как все результаты считывать из запросов.

Comment: Спасибо побежал читать)